# HTML & XHTML & XML - What is a URI in laymans terms?

Tags: uri

What is a URI in HTML, XHTML and XML?

Comment: I am too embarrassed to post this as an answer but take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI

Comment: @Steve: Agreed. That's a really nice wiki article. i especially like the diagram that shows the relationship between URIs, URNs and URLs. Although the OP is asking specifically how URIs are used from those three *ML doc types?

Comment: A link is one example of an absolute URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is simply a uniform string that identifies some resource <strike>on the 'net</strike>.

Comment: You can write a telephone number as a URI, that doesn't mean it's "on the net".

Comment: @Matthew - The URI is used on the net...not necessarily the resource.

Comment: @Justin No, that's the point. A *URL* is a URI which gives information about where the resource can be found. A URI is just an identifier like "Bob" (except more unique)

Comment: @Gareth - That's exactly what my answer says. It's a uniform way to *identify* a resource...not locate it (including information on locating the resource is what the URL is for).

Comment: Ok yes, my bad. Maybe clearer to make that distinction in the answer because that's the main sticking point about the issue

Comment: @Justin: Your answer can be interpreted as talking about "some resource [which is] on the 'net" - that's how I read it, and it doesn't apply to a tel: URI. But I think you're actually saying that the identification occurs on the net (but the resource isn't, necessarily). (This is a bit pedantic, but then conversations about URI vs URL tend to turn into that.)